# Hyphens and multiple prepositions

Tags: prepositions, punctuation, hyphenation

I keep stumbling across this problem. In a sentence such as: '...indicates that offers of or requests for assistance...' should there be hyphens to indicate that both the 'of' and 'for' relate to assistance? I've sometimes seen it written like this: '...indicates that offers of- or requests for- assistance...' Is there perhaps a grammatical rule when dealing with this type of situation? Help, please. Thanks.

Comment: You can't use hyphens.  You can use dashes.  You can also use commas or parentheses.  However, it's a question of style rather than grammatical correctness.

Comment: No, Sula. If you’d provided a complete example, it would prolly be obvious that *… offers of or requests for assistance…’ is fine by itself. *… offers of - or requests for -…* just might be better, and not to an extent that mattered.

If both *of* and *for* don’t relate to assistance, why exactly are they lumped together? 

There are broad grammatical rules in this type of situation and everything depends on context which again, would need a complete example… or three or more..

Strictly you do need dashes, not hyphens… and how many people will see a difference; much less, what it is?